# match a line using bash regex

Tags: regex, bash

I want to match a line that contains a word, but does not have semi-colon in it

This should match:

```
class test
```

this should not match

```
class test;
```

this should not match either

```
class test; // test class
```

this is what I was expecting to work, but it doesn't:

```
pattern="class [^;]*"

if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]
```

thanks

Comment: What about `class test // test class;` ?

Comment: Do not edit this question with your new question or remove details from this question that has answers.  Use the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button and post a new question providing [all of the details needed to get your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression is not [*anchored*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) which means that `[^;]*` will still match against all characters up to a possible `;` (and thus match as a whole). If you anchor the regex against the end of the line (`[^;]*$`) it will produce the results you are after:

```
$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/bash

pattern='class [^;]*$'
while read -r line; do
    printf "testing '${line}': "
    [[ $line =~ $pattern ]] && echo matches || echo "doesn't match"
done <<EOT
class test
class test;
class test; // test class
EOT
```

---

```
$ ./t.sh
testing 'class test': matches
testing 'class test;': doesn't match
testing 'class test; // test class': doesn't match
```

**TL;DR**: In other words, the bold part in

> **class test**; foo bar quux

matches your regex even though the string contains a semicolon which is why it always matches. The anchor makes sure that the regular expression only matches if there is no semicolon *until the very end of the string*.

Answer (score 1):

how about straightforwardly:

```
 pattern="^[^;]*\bclass\b[^;]*$"
```

`\b` word boundary was added, for matching `xxx class xxx` only, not matching `superclass xxx`

Answer (score 0):

Use `^[^;]+($|\s*//)`.  This means any number of non-semicolon characters (at least one) from the start of the string until either the end of the line or any number of spaces followed by two slashes.

http://rubular.com/r/HTizIXz2HA

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
pattern="^[^;]*class [^;]*$"`
```

This ensures the line don't have a ; before or after your `[^;]*` match.